# Dropdown Menu Options are Image (not text)

Tags: html, image, drop-down-menu

I want to ask about html dropdown menu. As we know, that option tag in html only support text. However, I need to create a drowp down menu that show list of image. I've searched for it. And I found several ways, including using css or jquery. However, that's not what I want. Here is, what I want to create:

```
<option value = blablabla><img src = "img/blbalba.txt"></option>
```

The code above is not working. Is there any sugestion to display dropdown menu like that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :)

A free light weight jQuery plugin that allows you to create a custom drop down with images and description.

What is so cool about this plugin!

- Adds images and description to otherwise boring drop downs.
- Allows JSON to populate the drop down options.
- Converts your HTML select element to ddSlick.
- Uses Minimum css and no external stylesheets to download.
- Supports callback functions on selection.
- Works as good even without images or description!

**http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo**

Comment: hi, i've tried that. But by using that way, the image will only shown as icon. And that's not what I want. What i want is, the image shown as the content of the dropdown menu, not only as icon. Do you've any suggestion to do it? Thanks

Comment: @user1814734: Sorry :( It's not possible. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html

Answer (score 0):

As You can't do that in plain HTML, but you can do it with JQuery.

Right now You can do like this

```
<select>
<option value="img1" style="background-image:url(images/img1.png);">image 1</option>
<option value="img2"  style="background-image:url(images/img2.png);">image 2</option>
<option value="img3" style="background-image:url(images/img3.png);">image 3</option>
<option value="img4"  style="background-image:url(images/img4.png);">image 4 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah that only works in Firefox as of time of posting.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will only render text inside a select tag, so, if you wan to use a selector that shows images instead of text, you cannot use a select you'll need to build your own selectable object.

That could be quite difficult to do. You can use different premade solutions that people on your situation developed before or try to reinvent the wheel.